# OCaml: retain value of variable with control statements

Tags: ocaml

I'm very new to OCaml / functional programming, and I'm confused about the implementation of some things that are relatively simple other languages I know. I could use any and all help.

Chiefly: in a program I'm working on, I either increment or decrement a variable based on a certain parameter. Here's something representative of what I have:

```
let tot = ref 0 in
for i = 0 to s do
    if test_num > 0 then 
        tot := !tot + other_num
    else
        tot := !tot - other_num
done;;
```

This is obviously not the way to go about it, because even if the `else` statement is never taken, the code acts as if it is, each and every time, presumably because it's closer to the bottom of the program? I know OCaml has pretty sophisticated pattern matching, but within this level of coed I need access to a handful of lists I've already created, and, as far as I understand, I can't access those lists from a top-level function without passing them all as parameters.

I know I'm going about this the wrong way, but I have no idea how to do this idiomatically.

Suggestions? Thanks.

**edit**
Here's a more concise example:

```
let ex_list = [1; -2; 3; -4] in
let max_mem = ref 0 in
let mem = ref 0 in
let () = 
    for i = 0 to 3 do
        let transition = List.nth ex_list i in
        if transition > 0 then (
            mem := (!mem + 10);
        ) else 
            mem := (!mem - 1);
        if (!mem > !max_mem) then (max_mem := !mem);
    done;
print_int !max_mem; print_string "\n";
in !mem;
```

At the end, when I print `max_mem`, I get 19, though this value should be (0 + 10 - 1 + 10 - 1 = 18). Am I doing the math wrong, or does the problem come from somewhere else?

Comment: The maximum value of !mem is 19. The final value is 18. I don't see any problem at all. The values at the end of the 4 times around the loop are 10, 9, 19, 18. (As a side comment, if this is the essence of your question, this is an excellent illustration of it.)

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine to me. It doesn't make a lot of sense as actual code, but I think you're just trying to show a general layout. It's also written in imperative style, which I usually try to avoid if possible.

The `if` in OCaml acts just like it does in other languages, there's no special thing about being near the bottom of the program. (More precisely, it acts like the `? :` ternary operator from C and related languages; i.e., it's an expression.)

Your code doesn't return a useful value; it always returns `()` (the quintessentially uninteresting value known as "unit").

If we replace your free variables (ones not defined in this bit of code) by constants, and change the code to return a value, we can run it:

```
# let s = 8 in
let other_num = 7 in
let test_num = 3 in
let tot = ref 0 in
let () =
    for i = 0 to s do
        if test_num > 0 then
            tot := !tot + other_num
        else
            tot := !tot - other_num
    done
in
!tot;;
- : int = 63
#
```

If you're trying to learn to write in a functional style (i.e., without mutable variables), you would write this loop as a recursive function and make `tot` a parameter:

```
# let s = 8 in
let other_num = 7 in
let test_num = 3 in
let rec loop n tot =
    if n > s then 
        tot
    else 
        let tot' =
            if test_num > 0 then tot + other_num else tot - other_num
        in
        loop (n + 1) tot'
in
loop 0 0;;
- : int = 63
```

It would probably be easier to help if you gave a (*edited to add:* small :-) self-contained problem that you're trying to solve.

The other parts of your question aren't clear enough to give any advice on. One thing that I might point out is that it's completely idiomatic to use pattern matching when processing lists.

Also, there's nothing wrong with passing things as parameters. That's why the language is called "functional" -- your code consists of functions, which have parameters.

**Update**

I like to write `let () = expr1 in expr2` instead of `expr1; expr2`. It's just a habit I got into, sorry if it's confusing. The essence is that you're evaluating the first expression just for its side effects (it has type `unit`), and then returning the value of the second expression.

If you don't have something after the `for`, the code will evaluate to `()`, as I said. Since the purpose of the code seems to be to compute the value of `!tot`, this is what I returned. At the very least, this lets you see the calculated value in the OCaml top level.

`tot'` is just another variable. If you calculate a new value straightforwardly from a variable named `var`, it's conventional to name the new value `var'`. It reads as "var prime".

**Update 2**

Your example code works OK, but it has the problem that it uses `List.nth` to traverse a list, which is a slow (quadratic) operation. In fact your code is naturally considered a fold. Here's how you might write it in a functional style:

```
# let ex_list = [1; -2; 3; -4] in
let process (tot, maxtot) transition =
    let tot' = if transition > 0 then tot + 10 else tot - 1 in
    (tot', max maxtot tot')
in
List.fold_left process (0, 0) ex_list;;
- : int * int = (18, 19)
#
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I didn't include the entirety of my code just for the sake of brevity, but I'll do that in a comment below. With respect to your answer, I have a few questions: what is the point of `let () = `... before the loop, and `in !tot` after it? I know you have to do `!tot` to get the contents of the reference, but what does it accomplish to call the variable at the end? Also, in your recursive function, what is the meaning of `tot'`, as opposed to `tot`?

Comment: (I'm going to edit my answer with this new info; these comments don't work well for back and forth questions.)

Comment: Also, I realized I edited your answer with my code rather than my own. Honest mistake.

Comment: (I rejected the edit... not sure what happens after that, I don't do it often.) It would be better to have a *small* self-contained example. Looking at a lot of code is hard, and it doesn't help as much as a careful small example.

Comment: This all helps a lot. Thanks so much. My code's working for now, so I'll return to this if I run into any other problems.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jeffrey's answer, let me second that this is not how you would usually write such code in Ocaml, since it is a very low-level imperative approach. A more functional version would look like this:

```
let high ex_list =
  let deltas = List.map (fun x -> if x > 0 then 10 else -1) ex_list in
  snd (List.fold_left (fun (n, hi) d -> (n+d, max (n+d) hi)) (0, 0) deltas)

let test = high [1; -2; 3; -4]
```